# R Passing parameters to lda() or qda()

Tags: r, optimization, modeling, lda

I'm trying to optimize my code by saving parameters in vector form and pass it to `lda()` for modeling. The following method works fine for lm, but not for qda or lda. The error message I received is highlighted in yellow.

```
intvars <- c("x*y","y*t","z*w")
intfm <- paste("clickthrough", "~", paste(intvars, collapse = " + "))
lda_model_int <- lda(intfm, data = s_train)
```

> Error in lda.default(intfm, data = s_train) : 'x' is not a matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to change your string to `formula` or you can `reformulate`

```
intvars <- c("x*y","y*t","z*w")
intfm <- reformulate(intvars,"clickthrough")
lda_model_int <- lda(intfm, data = s_train)
```

If you wanted to do it your way you will have to do

```
intvars <- c("x*y","y*t","z*w")
intfm <- as. formula(paste("clickthrough", "~", paste(intvars, collapse = " + ")))
lda_model_int <- lda(intfm, data = s_train)
```